# Call to undefined function get_userdata() in plugin

Tags: php, functions, users

After refactoring/restructuring files in my plug-in, I now get the
error

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_userdata()

after code

```
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
$current_user_meta = get_userdata($current_user_id);
```

in `mydomain.local/wp-content/plugins/my-project/my-project.php`
I also tried as it was before, in another .php file that was `required` by `my-project.php`

These lines are and were appearing quite early in my plug-in code ... am I missing some dependency before running them?

Comment: Where exactly did you put these lines?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot this so I have added it in the question. In the plug-in's main php file.

Comment: I think I found the reason. It may be that the lines are not correctly wrapped anymore ... Looking to check and correct it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution found: the reason was that the code including those lines were included in plug-in's main file and were wrapped in the shortcode launch anymore.

I had to put things in another file,like for example

```
function load_shortcode( $atts ){
    require_once(getPluginPath().('my-project.start.php'));
}
add_shortcode( 'my-project', 'load_shortcode' );
```

and lines had to be in `my-project.start.php`

---

`getPluginPath()` is NOT a native WordPress function, don't look for it, the only thing to know here is that it generates a path string.

Comment: This shouldn't have been needed to fix the problem, that's not how PHP works, and shouldn't have made a difference. Also, shortcodes are meant to return their output, not echo them